# How can I get around missing data in a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to pull data from the S&P and I get this error.

> FileNotFoundError: File b'S&P_dfs/LMT.csv' does not exist Now this
>   is is caused by this error: RemoteDataError('Unable to read URL:
>   {0}'.format(url)) pandas_datareader._utils.RemoteDataError: Unable to
>   read URL:
>   http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=LMT&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2000&enddate=Dec+20%2C+2016&output=csv

To get around this error I used a try and accept.  But now my next step is to pull financial data from the ticker csv file.  How can I have Python run and skip these missing files?

Comment: Can you please post your code? Am I correct in you having multiable URLs and one of them do not exist. So you would like it skip it, if it is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the code that does the fetching in a try-except block like this:

```
try:
   # Code that does the fetching from the urls
except pandas_datareader._utils.RemoteDataError as e:
   # Silence the error / skip the "bad" email 
   pass
```

This is not the encouraged behaviour though and it most certainly is not suitable for production.

A better approach would be to at least track which urls are "bad":

```
bad_urls={}

try:
   # Code that does the fetching from the urls
except pandas_datareader._utils.RemoteDataError as e: 
   bad_urls[url] = message
```

Comment: Thank you.  What would tracking the URL do?

Comment: Please consider upvoting / accepting the response if it helped you .
Tracking the messages can be used to sift through them in a post processing step. You could also write a logging mechanism, etc and provide fallbacks for those "bad" urls.